# Sudden unexplained change in perl behavior

Tags: terminal, homebrew, zsh, perl

I've been using zsh for at least a year, and I use perl in Terminal every day.

Today, for the first time ever, launching Terminal got this:

```
Last login: Thu Jul 13 08:50:35 on console
Attempting to create directory /Users/WGroleau/perl5
```

~/perl5 was actually created 24 May containing `man` and `lib` without that message, but it added the **empty** directory `bin` today.  `~/.cpan` was also created 24 May.

.zshrc contains

```
eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5)"
```

but the date on that file is 16 June and no other dot-files have been edited since then.  The last macOS update was 21 June, macOS_13.4_22F66 to macOS_13.4.1_22F82.  `brew update` also has not happened recently.

**Why would perl suddenly decide to add the empty `bin` and why the message now when it added lib and man silently?**

**Update:** Instead of that command doing two different things, it does **three**.  At the suggestion of "user1934428," I get the following:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/Users/WGroleau/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/Users/WGroleau/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```

So this time, it either assigned two environment variables which I will have to track down the purpose of, or displays how they were assigned at some other time.

Comment: Your `-M` does a `use` of the Module and runs the import routine. I don't know what is inside the module, but I guess any `BEGIN` block inside would be executed. You would have to look at the code of this module to see what's going on. In theory, it could download some updates from a remote location and therefore behave differently every time you call it. If you blindly do such an `eval`, you put yourself into the hands of that person who wrote the program to be evaluated. The interesting question is therefore, **why** you have this `eval`, and why did you put it in particular into .zshrc?

Comment: I don't remember for certain, but I think it was advice spit out by brew when I installed and or updated perl.  (Which I did because Apple's bundled perl was a significantly older version.)

Comment: You never checked, what the `eval` actually is producing??? At least it might make sense to ask in the Perl community about the effect of this statement, before blindly putting some eval into such a sensitive place. However, I don't really believe that the creation of the `bin` directory comes from this module, but in any case, this is something which you can analyze by yourself. After all, you have the source code available.

Comment: Again, it was probably put in by `brew` when perl was installed or updated. But it has been there since 16 June _or_earlier_ without issuing that message  And the directory it was "attempting to create" has actually been there since 24 May.

Comment: I can't say the `bin` was put in by this statement, but it ws created at approximately the time the message was produced which was also a time that `.zshrc` was run on a new shell window.  And it’s odd that it is in the `.zshrc` of my general account when `brew` only runs in the Admin account.

Comment: @user1934428, the "Module" you are referring to is local::lib, and I have no idea what or where that is.  Not that I could have examined it before I knew that "something" had added the reference to it into my .zshrc  But its parameter is the directory it was allegedly trying to create. Which was actually created long before the `eval…` was added.

Comment: You still did not tell us which code your _eval_  is producing. This would certainly be worth knowing. Directories don't spring into existence suddenly by themselves. Either a `brew update` did it, or some other code in your files. The only candidate you showed in your question is that strange _eval_, so this is certainly well worth examining.

Comment: I don't even know whether that eval does anything.  But it does reference the directory that the message was "attempting" to create—a directory that was already created long before the message appeared.  That's the point of the question: a command that invokes perl every time a shell is started for weeks suddenly (ONE time) announces it is attempting to create a directory when that directory has also been there for weeks—by (judging by time stamps) did create an empty `bin` under that directory.

Comment: _I don't even know whether that eval does anything._  Why don't you have a look then? Just do on the command line a `perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=$HOME/perl5` and see what you get! There is nothing hidden going on.

Comment: What I got every time I opened a shell (except one) was nothing.  What I got the _one_ time that inspired this question is listed in the question.  What I expected to get by putting it on the command line was one of those. Instead, I got what I am adding to the question.  So now, I have one command that does _three_ different things instead of two.

Comment: Well, what output do you get, when you enter the command I wrote in my comment???

Comment: The output I edited into the question.  Seeing what it sends to stderr doesn't tell me what it is doing.  Especially not the time it output a different message at the same time something created an empty directory.  And not the hundreds of other times I didn't know it was there because it printed nothing.

Comment: stderr does not matter, as you reasonably have written your `eval` so that it should ignore stderr anyway. But you see here what the eval does: It creates two environment variables, PERL_MB_OPT and PERL_MM_OPT. We do not know from this whether it creates the directories. To narrow this problem down, delete the `bin` directory and then run your `perl` command again. If the `bin` directory springs into existence again, you know that it was indeed created by this command.

Comment: If you google for the meaning of these environment variables, you will find that they are related to CPAN installations, and indeed it makes sense to me, that they also would need a `.../perl5/bin` directory. So you need to make up your mind: Do you want the CPAN stuff, and if yes, do you want to sit it at a different location?

Comment: Don't know whether I will ever need CPAN, but if that's all it is, it sounds safe.  I use exiftool a lot, and it depends (I think) on something on CPAN, but it works without that directory.  Still don't get why the same command produces two different outputs on two invocations and no output on most invocations.  Also, I didn't write it.  I was guessing that `brew` (home-brew) did it when installing exiftool or or a newer version of perl (even though brew is only run in a different account).  Or maybe exiftool installed it.

Comment: You will likely want to use CPAN, if you want to install new modules or tools from - well - CPAN. I personally would install Perl in a way that CPAN usage is easy, just in case I want to use it one day, but if I don't want to have the default directory layout (~/perl5/bin in your example), I would configure the top directory (~/perl5) to be at a different place. I would not try to reconfigure the fact, that lib and bin are located in parallel; this just begs for trouble. Also don't forget to put that bin directory into your PATH.

Comment: Note that you can install CPAN stuff completely manually. The integrated Perl support just makes it easier, in the same way that Homebrew makes it easier to install applications on the Mac.